# F# Find dictionary entries with some conditions

Tags: f#

```
let dTuples = new Dictionary<int, string * string * int>()
dTuples.Add(1, ("A", "OK", 1))
dTuples.Add(2, ("B", "NOK", 2))
dTuples.Add(3, ("C", "OK", 3))
```

I want to find the items from the dictionary where they have "OK" in the second element of the value part.
I also want to convert the result to an array of tuple without the key part of the dictionary.
For the above example, I need this:

```
let tuplesOK = [| ("A", "OK", 1); ("C", "OK", 3) |]
```

If you provide the code, please also add some explanation, so I can understand it better!
Thanks,
John

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution by Daniel clearly answers your question, but if you need to perform a lookup in the dictionary based on something else than the key, then you may want to consider using a different data structure, because there is no point in using the dictionary. Maybe you could just use a list:

```
let data =
  [ ("A", "OK", 1)
    ("B", "NOK", 2)
    ("C", "OK", 3) ]
```

And then perform lookup using `Seq.filter` just like in the solution by Daniel:

```
data |> Seq.filter (fun (_, ok, _) -> ok = "OK")
     |> Seq.toArray
```

Or if you need you're going to perform the lookup often, you could group the values using the second element (OK/NOK flag) and then store that in a dictionary using the `dict` function:

```
// build a dictionary with second element of the tuple as a key 
let lookupOk = data |> Seq.groupBy (fun (_, ok, _) -> ok) |> dict

// get a sequence of 'OK' values
lookupOk.["OK"]
```

Comment: Hi, Tomas Petricek:
Your code works, however, in my problem, I can only use dictionary due to the mutability issue.

Comment: @JohnJohn What kind of "mutability issue"? There shouldn't be a reason for using `Dictionary` specifically. Even if you need to modify the data strcture, you can add objects to generic mutable .NET `List<T>`, which is aliased as `ResizeArray<T>` in F#.

Comment: Hi, actually, I have to extract some strings from an XML file downloaded from internet.  But the number of XML strings is unknown before my program runs, therefore, I have to add all the downloaded XML strings to a dictionary and search for "OK" from the extracted string arrays.

Answer (score 5):

To check for the second tuple item matching "OK":

```
dTuples |> Seq.filter (fun (KeyValue(_, (_,ok,_))) -> ok = "OK") |> Seq.toArray
```

To get an array of tuples (without keys):

```
dTuples.Values |> Seq.toArray
```

If you don't need mutability, you can use the [dict<sup>[MSDN]</sup>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353774.aspx) operator to build a dictionary more concisely.

```
let dTuples = 
  dict [
    1, ("A", "OK", 1)
    2, ("B", "NOK", 2)
    3, ("C", "OK", 3)
  ]
```

I won't turn this into a tutorial. The code is pretty self-explanatory, and any gaps can be filled in by a quick search of MSDN.

Comment: Hi, Daniel:
Your code works for the first part: to get the qualified array of tuples, but I don't know how to get only the value part without the key.  From my development tool: VS 2010 Ultimate, there is no dTuples.Values I can use.
Let me know how can you get the value part of the dictionary entries.
Thanks,
John